# Simulating mouse movement in WPF in a test

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, mousemove

I have a WPF and C# project and I want to programmatically test a few hover events I have from a user's perspective. I could go ahead and just fire the event that occurs on user hover manually, but before I did that, I was wondering if it was possible to simulate mouse movement and put it on a location on the screen from code that then went ahead and fired the MouseMove (or whatever appropriate) events that bubbled down the visual tree.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite an old question but hopefully it could help anyone that come across it in future.

To put it in a clickable position (mostly the middle) of any control :

```
window.Mouse.Location = item.ClickablePoint; //using specific item
```

Or, similarly to what [@3aw5TZetdf does with Cursor.Position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905264/119775), you can set it to a specific location either relative to the current location or specifying a new one:

```
var point = window.Mouse.Location;
window.Mouse.Location = new Point(point.X - 200, p.Y - 200); // New location using current one. Replace 200 with your desire value
window.Mouse.Location = new Point(200, 200) // new location
```

Comment: WPF's window does not have a `Mouse` property.

Comment: The "window" object there is `Window` class from `TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems` namespace.
It has a Mouse (`AttachedMouse`) property from `TestStack.White.InputDevices` namespace

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a way to simulate mouse movement, but you can move the mouse programmatically:

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y); // x and y are integers that form a point
```

Or if you want it to go to the middle of a control:

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(this.Location.X + button1.Location.X + button1.Width / 2,this.Location.Y + button1.Location.Y + button1.Height);
```

Just replace `button1` with your desired control.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this was only possible in WinForms. The question is about WPF.